# Is there a way to prevent the URL from printing?

Tags: printing, browser

Whenever I print a webpage from my browser, the page's URL gets printed at the bottom of the page.

There is no option for this in the printer.
There is no option for this in the browser.

Is there a way to prevent the URL from printing ?

Comment: Which browser/OS?

Comment: Which browser are you using? IE does have various options in Page Setup to set headers and footers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your web browser, but in the print dialog there is usually an advanced setup or something.  If it's not there, look for a page setup.  You just need to turn off the headers/footers.

Comment: can we do that from code.. i am using php and javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page

Comment: There might be something in there that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the browser.

For example, if you go to the `about:config` page in Firefox, you'll see entries for `print.printheaderleft`, `print.printfootercenter` and so on.

These can be set individually.

To do this with Javascript, I think you'd need to code up an extension, since the alternative would be a whopping great security hole large enough to fly a 747 aircraft through.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use JavaScript to set these headers or footers.

However, you can change the settings in your own browser.

Alternatively, you could link to a PDF which prints *as is* by default.

Comment: This is how we solve it in my workplace.  Anything printable comes back as a PDF for many reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure if *printing* to PDF would create different results? Most browsers would not be aware that it's not a real printer and send the very same thing? (However, some browsers —such as Safari and OmniWeb on a Mac— generate clickable inline links when printing to PDF. Hence, these browsers somehow give the printing subsystem more information than the text alone.)

Comment: Sorry, misread your "link to PDF" as "print to PDF". That won't work for just any page a web site visitor sees, but indeed is a good idea for web site builders/editors.